# Which cardinality has the given set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Find :

Cardinality of $|\left\{ x \in \mathbb R : \space \text{the only digits in the fractional part of $x$ are } 2,3 \right\}|.$

Some examples :

$1.22222222...$

$1.333333333...$

$4.232322223....$

**My solution :**

I can look at the fraction part as $\left\{2,3\right\}^\mathbb N$
There are $\aleph_0$ numbers in the  integral part  of number.

Then there are $|\left\{2,3\right\}^\mathbb N|$ = $|\left\{2,3\right\}|^{|\mathbb N|}=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c$

Then $\mathfrak c \cdot \aleph_0 = \mathfrak c.$

Excuse my bad English!

Comment: Why $\forall x$?

Comment: Correct argument. The fractional parts are equivalent to infinite binary strings and it is well known that there are uncountable many such strings (easy to prove with Cantor's diagonal argument)

Comment: On the other hand, the set is a subset of $\mathbb R$, so its cardinality is the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument is correct. To be picky, you could call $S$ the set in question and define a map
$$
f\colon S\to\mathbb{Z}\times\{2,3\}^{\mathbb{N}}
$$
that associates to $x\in S$ the pair consisting of the integral part and the sequence corresponding to the fractional part.

This map is bijective, because of uniqueness of decimal expansion (only periodic nine or periodic 0 numbers are ambiguous and you have none of them).

Then $|S|=\aleph_0\cdot 2^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}$ by cardinal arithmetic.